# MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I want to receive some messages from IBM MQ based on java. So I write a very simple code to test what I want. Here is the sample code below.

```
    Const.MQ_QMANAGER = "QM.CREDITWEB3T.PC";
    Const.MQ_QUEUE_RECEIVE = "MQ.AIRPORTS";

    MQSimpleConnectionManager myConnMan = new MQSimpleConnectionManager();
    myConnMan.setActive(MQSimpleConnectionManager.MODE_AUTO);

    MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(Const.MQ_QMANAGER,
                    myConnMan);
```

When I new the `MQQueueManager`. It’s throw an error message. 
The error message is

> MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'

May someone help me to figure out what’s wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21410038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Your 1st posting is requesting that the connection to the queue manager be in "bindings mode".  This means you MUST run the code on the same server where the queue manager is running.

(2) Your 2nd posting is requesting that the connection to the queue manager be in "client mode" (over the network i.e.TCP/IP).  This means you can run the code on a remote server and connect to the remote queue manager using the network.

Answer (score 0):

After many times error and searched for the answer. Finally I found the solution. You needed to settle environmental parameter for MQ. I am sorry about that because I am so new about MQ. Here is the sample code below.

```
    // Host
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY,
            Const.MQ_HOST_NAME_PROPERTY);
    // Port
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY,
            Const.MQ_PORT_PROPERTY);
    // Channel
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY,
            Const.MQ_CHANNEL_PROPERTY);
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.CCSID_PROPERTY, XXX);
```